# Play audio through 2x HDMI monitors & 1x Aux Monitor

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, volume-mixer, stereo

I am trying to get all three of my monitors to play audio out of their speakers however I am having an issue with HDMI connections on two of the monitors overriding the AUX connections

Monitor 1:

- HDMI to DisplayPort
- AUX to AUX Splitter

Monitor 2:

- DVI-DL to DVI-DL
- AUX to AUX Splitter

Monitor 3:

- HDMI to HDMI
- AUX to AUX Splitter

Monitor 2 is working fine because the AUX connection isn't being overridden by a HDMI connection.

If I go into Sound > Recording and find "Stereo Mix" and change it to:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srQl2.png]

It works (all be it there being a slight audio delay that I haven't figured out how to fix yet), likewise if I change the settings to the other HDMI source, however I can't find a way to have a secondary Stereo Mix or a way to have it playback through multiple HDMI sources.

Is there any custom software out there or anything that allows me get around this?

I've tried to disable HDMI Audio sources, I've tried to uninstall HDMI Audio drivers but HDMI is still overriding AUX on the monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have speakers on my main monitor *but* [voicemeeter banana](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) should let you do this. I tested it with my speakers + one DP output , and presumably sound would have come out if I had one more speaker.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Some of the settings here arn't really needed (the additional master settings for example)  -  the important bits are to set A1, A2 and A3 for your sound outs(click on the down arrow, and pick your output)

Make sure that A1 A2 and A3 are highlighted as shown under the aux controls.

I've annotated this in shouty red letters since the UI is a bit cluttered.

Essentially it adds it own device to the audio mixer, and bypasses it for outputs. Works very well for many odd scenarios like yours.

Its donation-ware but not limited in any way.

Comment: Indeed this is working, the only problem is adjusting the volume. 1% vs 100% in Windows are the same, yet 0% mutes. If I use the hook it hooks on output A1 only, I got around this by using the macro keys like: http://i.imgur.com/VInBbQz.png